# Easier way to fuse two adjacent rows by indices into one in pandas dataframe

Tags: dataframe, concatenation, rows

If one has a dataframe in python and wishes two concatenate any two adjacent rows using their indices, what would be the simplest way?
Example:

```
       0      1
  0    a      b
  1    c      d
```

Output:

```
     0      1
0   a-b    c-d
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I got a work around, You could extract the rows you want to fuse and then turn them into lists. The lists can then easily be fused. Example: fusing two lists;

```
New_list=["{}-{}".format(list1_, list2_) for list1_, list2_ in zip(list1, list2)]
```

Then convert the list into a dataframe and transpose it:

```
DataFrame_row=DataFrame(New_list)



DataFrame_row1=DataFrame_row.transpose()
```

Lastly, concatenate the two dataframes, you could also easily delete the two original rows in the original dataframe:

```
NewDataFrame = pd.concat([DataFrame_row1, OriginalDataFrame])
```

Cheers.